# Python SFTP: Get Notification when Connection breaks

Tags: python, notifications, connection, sftp, paramiko

Is it Possible if the Connection to a Server cuts off for some reason that I get a Text or something, so I know that the Error has something to do with the Server?

```
import paramiko
import time

def connSFTP(ssh_key_filepath,host,user):
    #Fehleroptionen 1. Pfad zum SSH-KeyError
                        #-SSH-Key vorhanden?
                    #2.Host und/oder Username ist falsch

    k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(ssh_key_filepath) #SSH KEY
    c = paramiko.SSHClient()
    c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    c.connect( hostname = host, username = user , pkey = k )
    sftp = c.open_sftp()

    return sftp

def main():
    ssh_key_filepath = '/home/dtv/.ssh/id_rsa'
    hostname = 'HostAdress'
    username = 'user'
    sftp = connSFTP(ssh_key_filepath,hostname,username)
    print('Connected')

    time.sleep(30)

    #sftp.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I built in a sleep, so I can kill the procedure for the Connection and Simulate the Connection lost in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use exception handling with the following:

Raises:
BadHostKeyException – if the server’s host key could not be verified

Raises:
AuthenticationException – if authentication failed

Raises:
SSHException – if there was any other error connecting or establishing an SSH session

Raises:
socket.error – if a socket error occurred while connecting

Paramiko api documentation link: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked but i had to Import socket for socket.error